# How to get an array of last nonzero values in columns of matrix?

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, vector, find

I have a matrix `M`

```
M = [0,11,111;...
     0, 0,222;...
     0,33,  0;...
     4, 0,  0;...
     5, 0,  0]
```

I want a vector with the last nonzero values of each column.

```
nzvals = [5,33,222]  % how do I get this programatically?
```

`find(a)`  gives me the indices of all the non-zeroes **without column context**.
Even worse, `find(a,1,'last')` gives me **a single index**.
`nonzeros  = M>0` gives me an indicator matrix with a 1 wherever there's a nonzero value. But I don't see how to use that to get the last nonzero value of the column.

Perhaps somehow with `[~,idx] = unique(a,'last') > 0` ?

Or will I need to use [index construction](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/213023-how-to-extract-values-from-a-matrix-using-a-row-column-matrix) somehow? If so, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Invert the matrix, convert it to logical by [negating](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/not.html) it to get non-zeros and zeros converted to [`false`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/false.html) and [`true`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/true.html) respectively. Now find the indices of the minimum values of each column using [`min`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/min.html). This will find the indices of the first occurrence of `false` in each column of the inverted matrix. Note that first occurrences of `false` in the inverted matrix are same as last occurrences of non-zeros in the original matrix. Now use these indices and [`diag`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diag.html) to extract the required values.

Alternatively, instead of using `min` and finding `false` elements after negation, you can also use [`max`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/max.html) and find `true` elements after applying `logical` (i.e. converting zeros to `false` and non-zeros to `true`).

```
nzvals  = M(end:-1:1,:);
[~, ind] = min(~nzvals,[],1);   %Alternatively: [~, ind] = max(logical(nzvals),[],1);  
nzvals =  diag(nzvals(ind,:));
```

Comment: *Additional point*: if there is no non-zero value in a column, the above code will return zero for that column. If you want to remove that value or replace it with `NaN` or anything else, you would do something like `nzvals=nzvals(nzvals~=0)` or `nzvals(nzvals==0)=NaN` respectively

Comment: Usama you rock!